# Actually work vs Actually does work?

Tags: grammar, emphasis, do-support

Is there any differences between following two sentences. I have seen both in various places and I can't really find a difference between them.

> It actually works.
>
> It actually does work.

Does the latter more emphasis on the result ? Is it grammatically correct ? In my view however the latter should be incorrect.

Comment: The second sentence is actually ambiguous between two different parses: one in which _does_ is emphatic and _work_ is a verb (like _It **does** run_), and another in which _does_ means 'performs' and _work_ is a noun object (like _It does the job_). But since they mean the same thing, it hardly matters.

Comment: In physics, "it actually does work" means something completely different from "it actually works". A doorstop works, but it doesn't do work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They technically mean the same thing (and both are grammatically correct).

There is a difference, but it is subtle. It's more clear in spoken English, or at least easier if you add an emphasis where necessary (which I have done below).

> It works.

Plain and simple, the thing works; no implications here.

> It actually works.

Think of it more as *"You would think it wouldn't work, but it works."* Perhaps other products in the same category don't work, and this dispels any disbelief in the product's ability to work.

> **Alan:** This application does not work!
>   **Bob:** It actually *does* work, but you need the latest JVM installed.

*Even more* emphasis on the fact that you think it wouldn't work, but it does.

And if you want to add *even* more emphasis (but is on the brink of grammatically incorrect, and overuse of this might lead people to stop taking you seriously):

> It really does actually work.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that people will stop taking you seriously when you go too far. (In all seriousness, good post.)

Answer (score 4):

The first sentence is just a normal sentence. The second case is a use of *to do* as an auxiliary verb for [emotive emphasis](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv298.shtml), in an affirmative sentence.

> We do not normally use do or does in affirmative sentences, Ali, but
> we can use them for emotive or contrastive emphasis when we feel
> strongly about something:
>
> *She thinks he doesn't love her, but he **does** love her. He really does!
>
> You **do** look pretty in that new outfit! Quite stunning!
>  Are you all
> right? You **do** look a bit pale.
> **Do** please sit down.
> I don't see very
> much of my old friends now, but I **do** still email them.
> Was that a
> joke? I **do** believe you're teasing me!*

So, the difference between the sentences is the second sentence places emphasis on the verb *to work*.