# What's the difference between "I did eat" and "I ate"?

Tags: past-tense, do-support

In short, what is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I did eat my lunch an hour ago.
2. I ate my lunch an hour ago.

They both are past tense.
Honestly, I'm confused between them.

Comment: related: [emphasizing someone has definitely done something like “I did go there”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316154/emphasizing-someone-has-definitely-done-something-like-i-did-go-there) and [Actually work vs Actually does work?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155063/actually-work-vs-actually-does-work)

Comment: The first is an affirmation of what you did, with emphasis placed on answering the question of whether or not you did something. The second is a mere statement of fact.